# Redux selector malfunction

Tags: redux

[image: UserSlice]
The SelectUserName is only returning the first value of the name i.e. the P from Peart.
The same problem happens when I use the SelectUserAge. Anyone know why this could be? Thanks

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Actually I don't... but nevertheless.

Comment: How did you use `selectUserName`? Can you print the whole state to check if it's correct